# ViewBinding/DataBinding not working with <include>, returning View instead of Binding

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-viewbinding

I am using ViewBinding and I have layout nested using `<include>` like this:

```
activity_main.xml -> content_main.xml -> entry_card.xml
```

But if the name is `content_main.xml`, `binding.content` returns `android.view.View` instead of `ContentMainBinding`, so I cannot access `EntryCardBinding`.

What I've tried:

- Clean Project *(doesn't work)*
- Rebuild Project *(doesn't work)*
- Invalidate Caches... > Invalidate and Restart *(doesn't work)*
- Using `dataBinding` instead of `viewBinding` *(doesn't work)*
- Using *Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 RC 1* instead of *Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2* *(doesn't work)*
- Changing `<include>` id from `content` to `another_word` *(doesn't work)*
- Copying the folder and opening the copied folder **(works)**
- Changing filename to `content_mainn.xml` **(works)**

I spent the whole day trying to figure this problem out, but I don't know why it happens only in that specific folder. If I copy it, it doesn't happen...

**`activity_main.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/content"
            layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**`content_main.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Example"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**`MainActivity.kt`**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.content // Returns android.view.View instead of ContentMainBinding

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that renaming the layout file works. I had `content_main_alternate.xml`. Renaming it to `content_main_alternates.xml` or `content_alternate_main.xml` both worked. I tried renaming the parent layout and that didn't work. Weird bug still in Android Studio 2022.3.1 patch 2, and I'm sure it's an AS issue since it still compiles and runs fine with no build messages related to that issue.